# WARNING: Found both android-support-v4 and android-support-v13 in the dependency list

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to import the SliderMenu Demo and i get the following error in the project.
I successful imported the library but not able to import the library.

Lib: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

[image]

[image]
[image]

I am not able to delete the v13 file either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are targeting older devices (API 13<) then you should remove the v13 support lib. 
You are getting the warning because v13 already includes v4, but some of the API's for the v13 lib are only available for API 13+.

Comment: i am not able to remove v13 there is no option to delete the file

Comment: Look inside your libs folder... and remove it from your build path

Comment: what combination do you suggest for using anroid.app.Fragment with viewPager (only present in V4) and FragmentStatePageAdapter(only present in V13) ?

Comment: @NayAneshGupte The `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is available in the v4 support library. Look again :)

Comment: yes my mistake. but just to use fragments inside viewPager I have to go with Fragment from V4 because if I'm using anroid.app.Fragment then I have to use android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Because this pager adapter will always come into the picture when pager is there.And if this warning comes then v13 becomes just pointless without viewPager. Please let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere.